# in postgres, can one query the current listeners?

Tags: postgresql, listener

in the `notify / listen` for postgres, one listens through

```
listen channel
```

is there a way to query the current channels to which the session is listening?

have gone through doc with luck as yet.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  thanks - you continue to amaze me. can you post this as an answer - if not, will do myself later

Comment: Note that the question title contradicts the question. In the body, you ask for a list of channels the current session is listening too - that's completely distinct from a list of current listeners.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select * 
from pg_listening_channels()
```

This is listed in the chapter "System Information Functions":

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html

Comment: This will only show the channels listened to in the _current session_. Getting channels listened to by all sessions does not seem possible at this time:
https://www.postgresql-archive.org/pg-listening-channels-td5733802.html