# How notify works in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a written function that it's last row is:

```
Notify ALLOCWARE;
```

I know that this is a message via some sort of channel.
Where I can find which function is triggered due to this command?

Comment: No "function" is triggered. Any session that registered itself as a listeren will be notified.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That I know.. but where I can see who listen to that? I'm debugging the code and i'm stuck due to this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623503/in-postgres-can-one-query-the-current-listeners

Comment: @pozs `pg_listening_channels` shows channels, that current_session listens to, while OP wants to list sessions that listen to his channel

Answer (score 1):

The list of channels on which a given session is listening is stored in the backend's private memory (`listenChannels` in `src/backend/commands/async.c`), so there is no way to figure out on which channels other sessions are listening.

Comment: sessions only communicate with the server, not with each other. This notify trigger some action from the server but I can't figure out which.

Comment: That depends on what API you are using.

Comment: How do I know that? I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: Meh. But *how* do you use it? On the command line or from a program? In which programming language is the program that accesses PostgreSQL written, and which library does it use to access PostgreSQL?

Comment: I don't know. This is a code written by someone who is not here anymore.. If there is a way to check please let me know how. This is why i'm lost. I can't figure out who and where it's handled.

Comment: And you don't know in which programming language the code is written and what libraries it uses? Then you should get a programmer to look into these things for you...

Comment: it's plpython / pgsql . I am the programmer. I received responsibility for this system... there is no one to instruct me about it.