# How can I list all current channels?

Tags: postgresql

I can use `pg_listening_channels()` to see what channels the current session is listening on.  But I'd like put some systematic monitoring around channel usage.  Aside from building my own listener registration mechanism, is there a means to obtain this information for all sessions?

Answer (score 2):

[How notify works in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43604254/how-notify-works-in-postgresql)
has a very close question and according to Laurenz Albe

> The list of channels on which a given session is listening is stored
>   in the backend's private memory (`listenChannels` in
>   `src/backend/commands/async.c`), so there is no way to figure out on
>   which channels other sessions are listening.

So I assume there's no way currently to obtain this information for all sessions